# Process all text from nested divs inside ul tags using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have some HTML which looks like this one:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="some multiple classes here">
        <div class="some multiple classes here">
            <ul class="other classes">
                <li>
                    <div class="random">some text1</div>
                    <div class="random1">some text2</div>
                    <div class="random2">some text3</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="random">some text4</div>
                    <div class="random1">some text5</div>
                    <div class="random2">some text6</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="random">some text7</div>
                    <div class="random1">some text8</div>
                    <div class="random2">some text9</div>
                </li>
                <!-- here can appear more <li></li> elements -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The situation is a little bit complex:

- first, there are only a few `<li></li>` tags with the same `<div>` classes inside but different text. More, `<li></li>` (with the same `div`s) appear as time passes.

I struggled to find a solution of retrieving all `some textX` elements in a single loop (not necessary if not possible) using `xpath` and `selenium` but I couldn't find a away. More, when I finish all the `<li></li>` tags, I'd like to just wait for others to appear and take some actions.

The pseudo-code would be the following:

```
for mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath of ul'):
    # here get all the texts
    # process them
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all the divs that are direct children of li tags?

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li/div')
```

Or by css selectors

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > div')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the `<li>` tags using the `<ul>` and all the `<div>` tags using the `<li>` tags

```
divs = [] # will hold the divs
ul = driver.find_element_by_class_name('classes')
lis = ul.find_elements_by_tag_name('li') # list of the <li> tags
for li in lis:
    divs.append(li.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')) # add all the <div> tags to divs list

for div in divs:
    text = div.text
```

Another solution will be using contains on the "random" in the class

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class*="random"]')

for div in divs:
    text = div.text
```

Comment: For the first example I get an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @Alexander it should be `lis = ul.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')`, I updated my answer

Comment: Well, I knew this and I modified it before but I still get the same error. Any ideas why ?

Comment: @Alexander maybe the list declaration is the problem, try `divs = []`

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that I tried to print each element you wrote, but I got: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9b6579af-c027-43d6-98b4-9d14109303c0", element="{9e80dae6-dc89-4365-8306-e00aac001008}")>`

Comment: @Alexander this is because you printed WebElement. You need to print the element text `print div.text`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103205/discussion-between-alexander-and-guy).